# Why isn't margin-bottom:[value]% working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't understand why `margin-bottom` isn't working as expected in `.leftBar_fundo`. I tried in all divs inside `#div_leftBar`, but it still doesn't work. When I open two or more divs in the `leftBar`, they expand and end up overlapping the `footer`. I want to when I expand the div the footer goes down as well. But `margin-bottom` isn't really working. I used jQuery to make the content appear and disappear. HTML code:

```
<div class="body_container">
                <div id="div_header">
                    <div id="nav">
                        <div id="nav_wrapper">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                <a href="#">Example <img src="images/seta.gif" id="seta"/></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                        <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                        <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                        <a href="#">Example</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="div_leftBar">
                        <div class="leftBar_fundo">
                            <div class="leftBar_wrapper">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="top_li">
                                        <a class="top_link" href="">OPENS</a>
                                        <ul class="hidden_ul">
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </li>
                                    <li class="top_li">
                                        <a class="top_link" href="">OPENS</a>
                                        <ul class="hidden_ul">
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </li>
                                    <li class="top_li">
                                    <a class="top_link" href="">OPENS</a>

                                    <ul class="hidden_ul">
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
                                    <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
                                    <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>      
                    </div>  
                </div>



                <div class="div_content">
                    <div class="internal_div_content">
                        <div class="calendario_container">
                            <img src="images/calendario/calendario_jul.png" class="calendario_imagem" />
                            <h4 class="dia_calendario" >14</h4>
                        </div>

                        <h1 class="content_title">Título de exemplo</h1>
                        <hr style="width:100%; position:relative; top:1%" />

                        <div class="text_div_content">
                            <p>Ullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretiuLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                            Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede molliUllam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div id="div_footer">
                    <div id="footer_socials_container">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="images/socials/facebook.jpg" id="facebook_img" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" onmouseover="this.src='images/socials/facebook_hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/socials/facebook.jpg'" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="images/socials/twitter.jpg" id="twitter_img" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" onmouseover="this.src='images/socials/twitter_hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/socials/twitter.jpg'" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="images/socials/googlep.jpg" id="googlep_img" alt="Google Plus" title="Google+" onmouseover="this.src='images/socials/googlep_hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/socials/googlep.jpg'" />
                        </a>
                        <span id="seguir_mensagem">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="footer_container">
                        <div id="col1_container">
                            <ul id="footer_col1">
                                <h4>Example:</h4>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="col2_container">
                            <ul id="footer_col2">
                                <h4>Example:</h4>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


                        <div id="col3_container">
                            <ul id="footer_col3">
                                <h4>Example:</h4>   
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And Css code:

```
  body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#ffcc66;
    font-size:18px; 

}
.body_container {
    position: relative;
    height:1000px;

}

#div_header {
    background-color:#0000ff;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:3%;
}

 /* Nav bar at the top of the page */

#nav{
    background-color: #222;
    position:relative;
    top:80%;
}

#nav_wrapper{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;

}

#nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;

}

#nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #333;

}

#nav ul li a,visited{
    color: #ccc;
    display:block;

    text-decoration:none;

}

#nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}

/* Segundo conjunto de Links */

#nav ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:51px;
    left:476px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    border:5px solid #222;
    border-top:0;
    min-width:200px;

}

#nav ul ul li{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#nav ul ul li a, visited{
    color: #ccc;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color:#899;
}
#seta{
    position:relative;
    top:2px;

}

/*Left bar*/

#div_leftBar{
    width:15%;
    min-height:60%;
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    margin-bottom:30%;
    padding:0;
}

.leftBar_fundo{
    background-color:#222;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:30%;
}

.leftBar_wrapper{
    padding:15% 10% 10% 0%;
    margin-bottom:20%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

/* Content that is "underneath" .top_li*/

.hidden_ul{
    margin-top:20%;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}

.hidden_ul li{
    margin-left:20%;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:initial;
    font-size:14px;

}

.hidden_ul li a:hover{
    color:#999;

}

.top_li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:2px solid #222;
    border-radius:16px;
}

.top_li:hover{
    border:2px solid #333;

}

.top_link{
    padding-left:15%;

}

.top_link_alone{
    padding-left:15%;

}

.single_li{
    padding-left:15%;
    border:2px solid #222;
    border-radius:16px;

}

.single_li:hover{
    border:2px solid #333;

}

.leftBar_wrapper ul{
    list-style-type:none;

}

.leftBar_wrapper ul li{
    padding:8% 0 8% 0;
    color:#fff;

}

.leftBar_wrapper ul li:hover{
    background-color:#333;


}

.leftBar_wrapper ul li a, visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;


}


div.div_content{
    background-color:green;
    width:60%;
    min-height:85%;
    position:relative;
    left:18%;
    border:2px solid green;
    border-radius:25px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0 5% 0;

}

.internal_div_content{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius:25px;

}

.text_div_content{
    margin:3% 0 0 0;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:10%;


}

.calendario_container{
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    position:relative;
    left:6%;
    top:1%;
    float:left;
    z-index:9;
    margin-right:0;
    padding-right:0;

}

.dia_calendario{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:34%;
    font-size:23px;

}

.calendario_imagem{
    position:relative;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;

}

h1.content_title{
    text-align:center;

}

    /* Footer of the page */        

#div_footer{
    background-color:orange;
    width:100%;
    height: 40%;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:20%; 
}

#div_footer div ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#777;

}

#div_footer div ul li a:visited{
    color:#777;

}

#div_footer div ul li a:active{
    color:#555;

}

#div_footer ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding:3% 0 5% 20%;
    color:white;
}

#div_footer ul li {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 1% 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#div_footer div ul li a:hover{
    color:#999;
}

#footer_container{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:15%;
    height:85%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

#col1_container{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;

}

#col2_container{
    position:absolute;
    left:14%;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;

}

#col3_container{
    position:absolute;
    left:28.5%;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;

}

#col1_container, #col2_container, #col3_container{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;


}

#footer_col1, #footer_col2, #footer_col3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    right:5%;
    top:18%;

}
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.hidden_ul').hide();
$(".top_link").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("medium");
    return false;
});
```

});

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2C4dw/6/

What should I do to avoid this and make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by using floats. You have to add to both your `.div_content` and `.left_container` `float:left;` and then put `<div class="clear"></div>` just before your footer.
HTML code:

```
<div class="left_container">
    <div id="div_leftBar">
        <div class="leftBar_fundo">
            <div class="leftBar_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li class="top_li">
                        <a class="top_link" href="">Example</a>
                            <ul class="hidden_ul">
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            </li>
                            <li class="top_li">
                                <a class="top_link" href="">Example</a>
                                    <ul class="hidden_ul">
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Example</a></li>

                                    </ul>

                                    </li>
                                    <li class="top_li">
                                    <a class="top_link" href="">Example</a>

                                        <ul class="hidden_ul">
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
                                        <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>  
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                <div class="div_content">
                    <div class="internal_div_content">
                        <div class="calendario_container">
                            <img src="images/calendario/calendario_jul.png" class="calendario_imagem" />
                            <h4 class="dia_calendario" >14</h4>
                        </div>

                        <h1 class="content_title">Título de exemplo</h1>
                        <hr style="width:100%; position:relative; top:1%" />

                        <div class="text_div_content">
                            <p>Ullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretiuLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!--Added <div class="clear"></div>-->
                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div id="div_footer">

                </div>
```

CSS code:

```
    .left_container{
    min-width:15%;
    min-height:60%;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    /* Added float:left */


    }

    #div_leftBar{
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        margin-bottom:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index:90;

    }

    .leftBar_fundo{
        background-color:#222;
        position:relative;
        z-index:90;
    }

    .leftBar_wrapper{
        padding:15% 10% 10% 0%;
        position:relative;
        z-index:90;
        height:100%;
    }


    .hidden_ul{
        margin-top:20%;
        padding:0;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        clear:both;
        z-index:90;
    }

    .hidden_ul li{
        margin-left:20%;
        padding:0;
        list-style-type:initial;
        font-size:14px;

    }

    .hidden_ul li a:hover{
        color:#999;

    }

    .top_li{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:2px solid #222;
        border-radius:16px;
    }

    .top_li:hover{
        border:2px solid #333;

    }

    .top_link{
        padding-left:15%;

    }

    .top_link_alone{
        padding-left:15%;

    }

    .single_li{
        padding-left:15%;
        border:2px solid #222;
        border-radius:16px;

    }

    .single_li:hover{
        border:2px solid #333;

    }

    .leftBar_wrapper ul{
        list-style-type:none;

    }

    .leftBar_wrapper ul li{
        padding:8% 0 8% 0;
        color:#fff;

    }

    .leftBar_wrapper ul li:hover{
        background-color:#333;


    }

    .leftBar_wrapper ul li a, visited{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#fff;


    }

    div.div_content{
    background-color:green;
    width:60%;
    min-height:85%;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid green;
    border-radius:25px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0 5% 3%;
    float:left;
    /* Added float:left */

}

 /* Added .clear */
.clear{
    clear:both;

}

.internal_div_content{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius:25px;

}

.text_div_content{
    margin:3% 0 0 0;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:10%;


}

.calendario_container{
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    position:relative;
    left:6%;
    top:1%;
    float:left;
    z-index:9;
    margin-right:0;
    padding-right:0;

}

.dia_calendario{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:34%;
    font-size:23px;

}

.calendario_imagem{
    position:relative;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;

}

h1.content_title{
    text-align:center;

}



#div_footer{
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    height: 40%;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:0%;  
}

#div_footer div ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#777;

}

#div_footer div ul li a:visited{
    color:#777;

}

#div_footer div ul li a:active{
    color:#555;

}

#div_footer ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding:3% 0 5% 20%;
    color:white;
}

#div_footer ul li {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 1% 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#div_footer div ul li a:hover{
    color:#999;
}

#footer_container{
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:15%;
    height:85%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

#col1_container{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;

}

#col2_container{
    position:absolute;
    left:14%;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;

}

#col3_container{
    position:absolute;
    left:28.5%;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;

}

#col1_container, #col2_container, #col3_container{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;


}

#footer_col1, #footer_col2, #footer_col3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    right:5%;
    top:18%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the side bar overlaps with the footer is because you are setting the #div_leftBar as absolute. When you do that, the element is removed from the flow and not counted towards the the height of the parent element.

You need to do some re-factoring in your css. Try using position relative and floating it left, just don't forget to clear the float.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change your structure. Put left and right div in main container.

Like following

```
<div class="body_container">
  <div id="div_header">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Example</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Example</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Example</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Example</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Example <img id="seta" src="images/seta.gif"></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Example</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div id="div_leftBar">
      <div class="leftBar_fundo">
        <div class="leftBar_wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li class="top_li"> <a class="top_link" href="">OPENS</a>
              <ul style="display: none;" class="hidden_ul">
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="top_li"> <a class="top_link" href="">OPENS</a>
              <ul style="display: none;" class="hidden_ul">
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="top_li"> <a class="top_link" href="">OPENS</a>
              <ul style="display: none;" class="hidden_ul">
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
            <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
            <li class="single_li"><a class="top_link_alone" href="">Example</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div_content">
      <div class="internal_div_content">
        <div class="calendario_container"> <img src="images/calendario/calendario_jul.png" class="calendario_imagem">
          <h4 class="dia_calendario">14</h4>
        </div>
        <h1 class="content_title">Título de exemplo</h1>
        <hr style="width:100%; position:relative; top:1%">
        <div class="text_div_content">
          <p>Ullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretiuLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede molliUllam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div id="div_footer">
    <div id="footer_socials_container"> <a href="#"> <img onMouseOut="this.src='images/socials/facebook.jpg'" onMouseOver="this.src='images/socials/facebook_hover.jpg'" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" id="facebook_img" src="images/socials/facebook.jpg"> </a> <a href="#"> <img onMouseOut="this.src='images/socials/twitter.jpg'" onMouseOver="this.src='images/socials/twitter_hover.jpg'" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" id="twitter_img" src="images/socials/twitter.jpg"> </a> <a href="#"> <img onMouseOut="this.src='images/socials/googlep.jpg'" onMouseOver="this.src='images/socials/googlep_hover.jpg'" title="Google+" alt="Google Plus" id="googlep_img" src="images/socials/googlep.jpg"> </a> <span id="seguir_mensagem">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span> </div>
    <div id="footer_container">
      <div id="col1_container">
        <ul id="footer_col1">
          <h4>Example:</h4>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="col2_container">
        <ul id="footer_col2">
          <h4>Example:</h4>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="col3_container">
        <ul id="footer_col3">
          <h4>Example:</h4>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add new css like : This will clearing your float.

```
.main-content { overflow:hidden; }
```

Change style for  this class `#div_leftBar`

```
#div_leftBar{
    width:15%;
    min-height:60%;      
    margin-bottom:30%;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
}
```

[For live demo refer the Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2C4dw/8/)

Comment: Ok, now `#div_leftBar` has a margin, but it's affecting `#div_content`, it's pushing `#internal_div_content` and itens below to the end of the page. Is there a way to make it not happen?